# Copy Dataframe to column only if value exist in other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this.

```
   SMS                 Email 
   1               - or " " or nan
   2                     3
 - or " " or nan        100
- or " " or nan        - or " " or nan
```

Here  - or " " or nan means that position can be a dash or nan or a blank value.
Now i want an output dataframe like

```
SMS                   Email                Status
1                    - or " " or nan        1
2                      3                    2
- or " " or nan        100                  100
- or " " or nan     - or " " or nan       - or " " or nan
```

The Logic of output DF is like if **SMS or Email both have values  , the status column should have value of SMS,** the status column should not have nan,blank or dash values unless both sms and email are nan or blank or -.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Status']=df[['SMS','Email']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce', axis=1).bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: Thank you , can you please tell which part in your code snippet is defining SMS as default ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Status']=df[['SMS','Email']].replace('[^0-9]+',np.nan,regex=True).bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
print(df['Status'])
```

---

```
0      1
1      2
2    100
3    NaN
Name: Status, dtype: object
```